# Retrieve all email campaigns in a non-Sitecore context

Tags: xconnect, marketing-definitions

Sitecore Version: 9.1 Update 1

I am trying to retrieve all email campaigns in a non-Sitecore context. To do that, First I Constructed the definition manager in a non-Sitecore context:

```
private static CampaignDefinitionManager CreatecampaignManager()
    {
        var loggerFactory = new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory();
        CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions options = CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["thumbPrint"]);
        IHttpClientHandlerModifier[] handlers = { new CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier(options) };
        var refDataClient = new ReferenceDataHttpClient(
            new DefinitionEnvelopeJsonConverter(),
            new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xConnectUrl"]),
            handlers,
            new Logger<ReferenceDataHttpClient>(loggerFactory)
        );
        var repo = new CampaignDefinitionReferenceDataRepository (
            refDataClient,
            new CampaignDataConverter(),
            new GuidMonikerConverter(),
            new DefinitionOperationResultDiagnostics()
        );
        var def = new NotConfiguredDefinitionFieldLabelResolver();
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<ITaxonomyManagerProvider, TaxonomyManagerProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITaxonomyClassificationResolver<ICampaignActivityDefinition>, DefaultClassificationResolver<ICampaignActivityDefinition>>();
        services.AddSingleton<FieldTaxonomyMap<ICampaignActivityDefinition>>();
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var classificationResolver = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITaxonomyClassificationResolver<ICampaignActivityDefinition>>();
            return new CampaignDefinitionManager(
            repo,
            classificationResolver,
            def,
            new NotSupportedSearchProvider<ICampaignActivityDefinition>(),
            new ActivationRetryingObservableFeed<ICampaignActivityDefinition>(new Logger<ActivationRetryingObservableFeed<ICampaignActivityDefinition>>(loggerFactory)),
            new DummyDeletecampaignObservableFeed(),
            new DefaultDefinitionManagerSettings()
        );
    }
```

And then using this manager, calling getAll method:

```
ResultSet<DefinitionResult<ICampaignActivityDefinition>> campaigns = manager.GetAll(new CultureInfo("da"), new RetrievalParameters<ICampaignActivityDefinition, string>());
```

But after doing all this, getting this error:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The marketing definition field label resolver has not been configured
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.NotConfiguredDefinitionFieldLabelResolver.get_FieldList()
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2.InitializeLabelResolver(IDefinitionFieldLabelResolver definitionFieldLabelResolver)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2..ctor(IDefinitionRepository`1 repository, ITaxonomyClassificationResolver`1 classificationResolver, IDefinitionFieldLabelResolver definitionFieldLabelResolver, IDefinitionSearchProvider`1 searchProvider, Boolean isReadOnly, IActivationObservableFeed`1 activationFeed, IDeleteDefinitionObservableFeed`1 deleteDefinitionFeed)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Campaigns.CampaignDefinitionManager..ctor(ICampaignDefinitionRepository repository, ITaxonomyClassificationResolver`1 classificationResolver, IDefinitionFieldLabelResolver definitionFieldLabelResolver, IDefinitionSearchProvider`1 searchProvider, IActivationObservableFeed`1 activationFeed, IDeleteDefinitionObservableFeed`1 deleteDefinitionFeed, IDefinitionManagerSettings settings)
```

Any idea, how to resolve this error to get all email campaigns in a non-Sitecore context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the `DefinitionFieldLabelResolver` as an `NotConfiguredDefinitionFieldLabelResolver`, which will throw an `InvalidOperationException` for each method that it implements

It should be enough to change the type from `NotConfiguredDefinitionFieldLabelResolver` to `EmptyDefinitionFieldLabelResolver`. This class can be found in the `Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Definitions` namespace (Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.dll).

Comment: Thanks Maarten, That worked for me :)